# How to use White Gaussian Noise for dataframe using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, normal-distribution, whitenoise

I had some data with missing values (around 27% from total data that were missing) and I filled them with mean's value (the average) and they created a line as shown figure.

[image]

So now I want to implement the white gaussian noise (WGN), to make them mimic the other noises randomly. I'm not sure how to use WGN in my data and every time i search i find only simple equations.

Are there any way to use WGN in my dataframe using python?

Comment: You should provide a Minimal, reproducible example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: It's a suggestion, but instead of generating a white gaussian noise to fill your data, wouldn't you want to try to impute the missing values? Depending on your data, some very simple approaches sometimes work great! Stuff like py-soft-impute are really easy to use practically.